# Why does EntityFramework 6 not support explicitly filtering by Discriminator?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, discriminator, tph

The following is a small EF6 Program to demonstrate the issue.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public abstract int TypeId { get; }
}
public class SubA : Base
{
    public override int TypeId => 1;
}
public class SubAA : SubA
{
    public override int TypeId => 2;
}
public class SubB : Base
{
    public override int TypeId => 3;
}
public class SubC : Base
{
    public override int TypeId => 4;
}

public class DevartContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }

    public DevartContext()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Base>()
            .Map<SubA>(x => x.Requires(nameof(SubA.TypeId)).HasValue(1))
            .Map<SubAA>(x => x.Requires(nameof(SubAA.TypeId)).HasValue(2))
            .Map<SubB>(x => x.Requires(nameof(SubB.TypeId)).HasValue(3))
            .Map<SubC>(x => x.Requires(nameof(SubC.TypeId)).HasValue(4));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DevartContext ctx = new DevartContext())
        {
            // prevent model-changes from wrecking the test
            ctx.Database.Delete();
            ctx.Database.Create();

            var result = ctx.Bases.Where(x => x.TypeId == 1);
            // throws on materialization, why?
            foreach (var entry in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The jist of it is this: We have a TPH-Model with an explicitly configured Discriminator (`TypeId` in this case). We then try to query a specific subtype using that TypeId because using the `is` operator in our hypothetical example would also return SubAAs, not just SubAs.

I could obviously modify the above to something like `Where(x => x is SubA && !(x is SubAA))` but this is obviously going to break as soon as I add SubAB, and automating this by building an exact-filter-linq-to-entities-helper-method is obviously really slow because that method has to do a decent amount of reflection. Not to mention that the generated SQL of the above is horrendous because EF/My SQL Provider does not optimize it properly.

Now trying to do the above results in a `NotSupportedException` being thrown when the query gets materialized, which basically states that because `TypeId` is not a member of the Entity, I cannot use it for filtering.

I went to look around for ways to circumvent this, but the best thing I could find was a snippet for automatically generating the `Where(x => x is SubA && !(x is SubAA))` version to solve the problem, which is likely to be what I will have to do to get around this.

So my question is: Why does EntityFramework not support this?

Comment: Because the privileged elite want to rule every aspect of our lives, this is just one aspect of their subtle control of our every waking moment

Comment: In seriousness, how does finding out why help your situation? Likely the answer is because it just doesn't. Will that help your problem? Probably not. Isn't the better question how do I get around this?

Comment: @Liam, actually, I think the privileged elite are working on c# 7.0, you'll have to pin this one on the deluded and forgotten.

Comment: We stopped using EF6 and switched to Dapper, EF wasn't, reliable or fast enough. In the end, it was just easier to write the SQL ourselves.

Comment: @Liam no I already mentioned that I can get around this problem using the really ugly and bad `(x is Thing) && !(x is OtherThing)` cascade, so thats likely what I will end up doing. I am really mostly curious if there are any design reasons on why this results in an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This soultion working excatly as you wish donot change anything ^^ "never change a running system" :)

You can use enum instead of integers, this give your code more type safety!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (DevartContext ctx = new DevartContext())
  {
    // prevent model-changes from wrecking the test
    ctx.Database.Delete();
    ctx.Database.Create();
    ctx.Bases.Add(new SubA());
    ctx.Bases.Add(new SubAA());
    ctx.Bases.Add(new SubB());

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    var result = ctx.Bases.Where(x => x.TypeId == 1);
    // throws on materialization, why?
    foreach (var entry in result)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(entry);
    }
  }
   Console.ReadLine();
  }


public abstract class Base
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual int TypeId { get; protected set; } 
}
public class SubA : Base
{
  public override int TypeId { get;protected set; } = 1;
}
public class SubAA : SubA
{
  public override int TypeId { get; protected set; } = 2;
}
public class SubB : Base
{
  public override int TypeId { get; protected set; } = 3;
}
public class SubC : Base
{
  public override int TypeId { get; protected set; } = 4;
}

public class DevartContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }

  public DevartContext()
  {
  }
}
```

Result in DB:

```
Id  TypeId  Discriminator
1   1       SubA
2   2       SubAA
3   3       SubB
```

Comment: `ctx.Bases.Add(new SubA { TypeId = 4 });` oops, I broke it :o) To be more clear: My problem is that this does not seem safe - it also adds an additional database field next to the Discriminator used, which is a bit annoying. Lastly, the original question wasn't how I can get around the issue (there's various ways I know of and have tried) but rather why they chose to design it that way. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I have added the keyword protected to the property. vote plz and, if this solve the problem then mark it as anwser :-)

Comment: It is still reasonably easy to break - just overwrite it from within one of the subclasses - or accidentally choose a duplicated one :) My own solution to the problem is similar to yours, but basically unbreakable (it does require configuration on the context though - but I can easily automate that). I have marked your answer as useful, because it is, but it does not answer the question "Why does EntityFramework not support this?" which is why I will not mark it as accepted answer. I hope you understand.

Comment: If you want to use TypeId as discriminator for TPH you must not use it for anything else => you cannot have it as property --> mapping error in EF this is a desgin decision in EF!

Comment: I understand that this is the case, but I do not understand why they designed it the way they did - in any case I will wait if anyone knows anything precise about this, if nothing comes up I will mark your answer as the accepted one since it's close enough :)

Comment: The reason is that entity type in inheritance is immutable.
If you change TypeId in any class would change the type of the entity but .NET is not Duck typing so you cannot change the type of existing instance.

Even if the property setter (TypeId) is protected you can change within the entity type. You must have a setter becasue EF need that to fill the data.
If you are not convinced with this answer then I give it up.

Comment: Since nobody else came up with a more satisfying explanation and yours is close enough (even though I still have to do some tests on manual discriminator configuration because I bet there's a bunch of silly stuff you CAN do with it) I will mark your answer as the accepted one. Thanks a lot!